# Meta programming Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this piece of code:

```
@timesheets.each do |ts|
  row = [
    ts.time_start.to_date,
    ts.time_start.to_time,
    ts.time_end.to_time,
    ts.task_link.project.client.name,
    ts.task_link.project.name,
    ts.task_link.task.name,
    ts.notes
  ]
  row.pop(3) if !@time_report.show_money
  sheet.add_row row, :style => [date_format, time_format, time_format, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, money_format, money_format, nil]
end
```

Now I want the user to be able to set the order him/herself.  I would create a hash containing all the possible values (and also matching styles).  But how do I integrate that into this procedure?  I looked up some info about metaprogramming but that seems to be mostly with define_method.  Is that the best option here?

Edit: I thought I had it because I could do:

```
Fields = [{'fieldname' => 'time_start', 'caption' => 'Date', 'type' => 'to_date', 'style' => 'date_format'},
{'fieldname' => 'time_start', 'caption' => 'Start', 'type' => 'to_time', 'style' => 'time_format'},
{'fieldname' => 'time_end', 'caption' => 'End', 'type' => 'to_time', 'style' => 'time_format'}]
...
```

And then be able to query like this:

```
@timesheets.each do |ts|
  row = []
  Fields.each do |f|
    row.append(ts[f].to_date)
  end
end
```

The 2 problems I'm having with this is:

How do I handle the 'ts.task_link.project.client.name' ?

```
ts[task_link.project.client.name]
```

is a no-go.

Second problem: How can I integrate the to_date, to_time, etc... ?

Comment: Woah! That's a lot of [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) violations...

Answer (score 1):

A level of abstraction would make this much simpler. Create

RowEntry and Row

classes that encapsulate data format knowledge and simple ask each entry for it's display format. I don't really see any MetaProgramming required.

This line

```
sheet.add_row row, :style => [date_format, time_format, time_format, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, money_format, money_format, nil]
```

Becomes

```
sheet.add_row row.entries, row.style
```

More details:

RowEntry is essentially a struct that records both the value and the display style.

Row is an Array of RowEntry objects that knows how to extract both a plain Array of values and a plain Array of styles from the RowEntry Objects.

Comment: Hi Fred, I'm not seeing it yet (I'm no Ruby expert).  Will look more into it tonight.  The style I think I understand, but how do I go about the to_date, to_time, to_s that is also dependant on the choosen item?